# Prove whether the following is a subgroup of Sn.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$σ∈ S_n$ , $ n∈\mathbb{N}$

$U_σ :=$ {$τ ∈ S_n | σ ◦ τ = τ ◦ σ$} ⊂ $S_n $

I know that the identity element is part of U.

Now i have to show that for every $a,b∈$ $U$,  $ab^{-1}$ ∈ $U$.

I dont know how to show that $b^{-1}$ ∈ $U$.

Could you please give some tips ?

Comment: This is true in *any* group: you $\;U_\sigma\;$ is called "the centralizer" of $\;\sigma\;$ Google it.

Comment: $\sigma\tau=\tau\sigma$ is the same as $\tau^{-1}\sigma=\sigma\tau^{-1}$ after multiplication by $\tau^{-1}$ on both sides.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{aligned}
 σ ◦ τ = τ ◦ σ &\Leftrightarrow σ ◦ τ ◦ τ^{-1} = τ ◦ σ ◦ τ^{-1}\\
&\Leftrightarrow σ  = τ ◦ σ ◦ τ^{-1}\\
&\Leftrightarrow τ^{-1} ◦ σ  = τ^{-1} ◦ τ ◦ σ ◦ τ^{-1}\\
&\Leftrightarrow τ^{-1} ◦ σ  =  σ ◦ τ^{-1}\\
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Could you try explain how you came up with multiplying by $τ^{−1}$ ?

Comment: This is natural as you want to prove that $\tau^{-1} \in S_n$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: use the fact that $1=bb^{-1}=b^{-1}b$ where $1$ is the identity. You know $1$ commutes with $\sigma$ as does $b$.